# Bind knockoutjs to javascript object property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, devextreme

I'm new to Knockoutjs, so please bear with me.

I want to knocoutjs bind a DxForm (DevExpress) to an javascript object property, but I get an error ... "Cannot read property 'items' of undefined".

I am uncertain if this is a knockout problem, DevExpress problem or just incufficient coding skills from my part.

Here's my code...

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="dxForm: frm.options"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var that = this;

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Faste...
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    that.frm = {
       items: ko.observable(undefined),
       data: ko.observable(undefined),
       instance: ko.observable({}),
       options: {
          items: that.frm.items,
          formData: that.frm.data,
          onInitialized: function(e) {
             that.frm.instance(e.component);
          },
       },
    };

    return {
       frm: that.frm,
    };

 };

 var vm = new viewModel();
 ko.applyBindings(vm);

 var items = [{
    "dataField": "test",
    "editorOptions": {
       "type": "date",
       "pickerType": "calendar",
    },
    "editorType": "dxDateBox",
    "name": "Test",
    "visible": true
 }];

 var data = {
    test: 10,
 };

 vm.frm.data(data);
 vm.frm.items(items);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MojoDK/ke395v2c/3/

I want to bind to objects since I'm going to use several DxForm objects and I like to keep the code to each DxForm in an object (easier to read).

Any idea why it fails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have a problem with closure in your **frm**.

The **that** property in **frm** object do not exist you should use **this**...

But in your **onInitialized function**, **this** and **that** will not target your **viewModel** object...

So this way, the easiest is to declare options object later :

```
 that.frm = {
       items: ko.observable(undefined),
       data: ko.observable(undefined),
       instance: ko.observable({})
    };

         that.frm.options = {
          items: that.frm.items,
          formData: that.frm.data,
          onInitialized: function(e) {
             that.frm.instance(e.component);
          },
       };
```

**Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ke395v2c/5/)**

Comment: Oh ... ok ... I see. Thank you for helping me out here! I will use your solution.